# SKAction with duration: 0 doesn't work - SpriteKit (Language: Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games, skaction

I am trying to make a fairly simple running animation by changing 2 images every 0.15 seconds and moving the character slightly up, when it has the running image, and slightly down when it has the other. It would work properly if I have 0.5 seconds as duration, or even 0.1, but when I change it to 0, or even 0.0001 the character doesn't move at all. (the image changing works properly)

```
let movingUp = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: self.position.x, y: self.position.y + 10), duration: 0)
let waiting = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.15)

let movingDown = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: self.position.x, y: self.position.y - 10), duration: 0)

let movingSequence = SKAction.sequence([movingUp, waiting, movingDown])
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(movingSequence))

let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(runningTexturesArray, timePerFrame: 0.15)
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animateAction)

self.runAction(repeatAction)
```

I also tried moveBy, got the same result. I need to mention when I set the duration to 0.1 I got a strange behaviour having the character shivering up and down (quicker than it should). It has physics body applied because I want to use collide detection later, but I've set affectedByGravity to false. I was thinking that maybe the physicsWorld has some kind of air, which blocks the character from moving freely while in "vacuum" it could do that.

Thank you in advance for any answer. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this action? It looks like it will just jump a few points up and then back to its original position with no motion.

Comment: If it takes 0 seconds to move, why don't you just eliminate the need for an SKAction and change the y-Position of the node?

Comment: The purpose of the sequence is just to move the character a slightly up while image1 is shown, and move it down when the image2 is shown. As this is happening fast it will give an 8bit choppy running motion style to the game. Thanks I will try leaving the SKAction out.

Comment: I don't know how to make a sequence of those movements without using `SKAction.sequence(action1, action2)`

Comment: Which delay are you referring to changing? The delays in `movingUp` and `movingDown` or the delay in `waiting`?

Comment: The `movingUp` and `movingDown` should happen in 0 seconds so the time between is `SKAction.waitForDuration(0.15)` But I don't have problem with the delay thing. Just the movement doesn't happen if I set 0 duration.

Comment: I'm wondering if this has to do with update loop timing. As an experiment, could you try changing `moveDown` to be `position.y - 50`? You will be able to tell if the action ran (without the expected animation) because your object landed in the "wrong" spot, or if it never moved at all because your object is still in the original spot.

Comment: Can you achieve the "choppy running" effect by offsetting the images up/down in an image editing app?

Comment: Can you try substituting 0 with nil? See if that works.

Comment: I've tried all, but unfortunately nothing seems to be working. :/ I guess I will go with "cheating" and just move the character in Photoshop. I thought I could do it in a more elegant way, but this one seems legit. Thank you all guys!

Comment: I think adding the choppy behavior as part of the animation sequence is a valid (and possibly the best) approach and not "cheating".

Comment: I see your point and already changed the app. Thank you for your help!